# vscode pylance memory limit

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, electron

I'm using vscode on a very large python project (more than 100K files).

pylance server keeps crashing on OOM.
Only thing that helps is limiting the number of indexed files.

I've traced the issue to "Code Helper (Plugin)" process of vscode that cannot go above 4GB.

I saw many posts about v8 pointer compression limiting memory to 4GB and that is the cause of this issue.

1. Can the memory usage of indexing be reduced to fit in the 4GB limit? I still want to index all files and unfortunately there are no directories that can be excluded.
2. If not, I saw some post describing the option to have viscose use external node which is compiled without v8 pointer compression. Can someone point me to explanation on how to accomplish that?

I've searched for an answer to this for quite some time and there is a lot of confusing info. Sorry if this has been asked/answered before.

Comment: please read through existing Q&A in https://www.google.com/search?q=vscode+extension+%22code+helper%22. is yours a duplicate of any of the existing ones?